# Is there a way to hide an object in a queryset in Django models?

Tags: django

Like you see the codes below, I'm manually using an attribute `status` in `Store` model to show my stores in `HTML Templates`. The problem is the more codes I make, the more repeating codes happen.

I'm trying to find a way to avoid those inefficient repetitions. Is it possible to set up in `models.py` to show only active stores to be shown in HTML templates?

I'm asking this because I've already done a similar thing to this. I have a string type attribute, but I need it in a list format in my templates, so I made a function to call it only with a list format. But, I can't figure out how to hide inactive stores in the same way.

Can anyone give me some suggestins for this?

**models.py**

```
class Store(models.Model):

    status = models.CharField(max_length=20,
        choices=(
            ('active', 'Active'), # ('Stored value', 'Label shown on the UI')
            ('inactive', 'Inactive'),
        ),
        default='inactive')
    ...
```

**HTML Templates**

```
{% if store.status == 'active' %}
    ... Show store
{% else %}
    ... Do not show store
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, though, People need to select only a subset of the complete set of objects. To refine the initial QuerySet, Here are the two most common ways to proceed:

Use **`filter()`** or **`exclude()`** with your **queryset** before sending it to the template.

> filter(kwargs**)
>   *Returns a **new QuerySet** containing objects **that match** the given lookup parameters.*

```
active_stores = Store.objects.filter(status='active')
# send active_stores to template
```

or

> exclude(kwargs**)
>   *Returns a **new QuerySet** containing objects **that do not match** the given lookup parameters.*

```
active_stores = Store.objects.exclude(status='inactive')
# send active_stores to template
```

In your template, you can loop through without a problem of **inactive stores**

```
{% for store in active_stores %}
    {{ store }}
{% empty %}
    No stores
{% endfor %}
```

See further explanations in the [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters)

Comment: Great answer, you can also chain these functions together in case the data you need isn't quite black and white :) e.g: `Store.objects.filter(modelField=x).exclude(name__contains="mystore")`

Comment: Agreed, that's why SO is here!

Answer (score 2):

Do not filter in the template language, filter in Python. From within the view function and/or class, make sure to filter the queryset:

```
objs = stores_queryset.filter(status='active')
```

Then work with the filtered `objs` in the template, and just iterate over `objs` without a conditional.  It's best to keep logic out of templates entirely, always passing in the correctly prepared context data.